# Play/Scala: use Redirect in ActionBuilder

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to build a simple action to use in Play controller to check if the session is active:

```
import play.api.mvc._
import scala.concurrent._

object AuthAction extends ActionBuilder[Request] {

    def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (Request[A]) => Future[SimpleResult]) = {
        if (request.session.isEmpty) {
            //Need to redirect to login page    
            Redirect("/login")
        } else {
            //Session is found, continue Action as normal
            block(request)
        }
    }

}
```

Problem is, it doesn't recognize `Redirect`. How do I get it to work in this scope? I want to use this action in my controllers where authorisation is required:

```
object Application extends Controller {

    def index = AuthAction {
        Ok(views.html.index("You are logged in."))
    }

}
```

These two would be different files.

Side question: what exactly is "A" in `invokeBlock[A]` and `Request[A]`?

I'm on Play 2.2.1, Scala 2.10.3, Java 1.8 64bit

**UPDATE:** Tried this, it doesn't give any errors any more, but it doesn't work - Redirect seems to be ignored.

```
import play.api.mvc._
import scala.concurrent._
import play.api.mvc.Results._

object AuthAction extends ActionBuilder[Request] {

    def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (Request[A]) => Future[SimpleResult]) = {
        if (request.session.isEmpty) {
            Redirect("/login")
        }
        block(request)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally stumbled upon a solution. In this case custom action "AuthAction" will redirect to the login page if the condition (session present) is not met:

```
import play.api.mvc._
import scala.concurrent._
import play.api.mvc.Results._

object AuthAction extends ActionBuilder[Request] {

    def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (Request[A]) => Future[SimpleResult]) = {
        if (request.session.isEmpty) {
            Future.successful(Redirect("/login"))
        } else {
            block(request)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to include `import play.api.mvc.Results._`

From the official [docs](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.1/ScalaBodyParsers),

The `A` type is the type of the request body. We can use any Scala type as the request body, for example `String, NodeSeq, Array[Byte], JsonValue, or java.io.File`, as long as we have a body parser able to process it.

To summarize, an `Action[A]` uses a `BodyParser[A]` to retrieve a value of type `A` from the HTTP request, and to build a `Request[A]` object that is passed to the action code.

Comment: It seems I got a little bit closer, but it still looks like a dead end - `Redirect` doesn't work and it also asks to return `Future[SimpleResult]` whatever that is...

Comment: Ah yes, Play 2.2 wants a Future.successful... I believe the else clause is required.

Answer (score 0):

its not redirecting if the the condition is not met

object Authentication extends ActionBuilder[Request] {

```
def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (Request[A]) => Future[SimpleResult]) = {
    if (request.cookies.get("user").isEmpty) {
        Future.successful(Redirect("/expired"))
    } else {
        block(request)
    }
}
```

}